# Efficient way to import a few hundred images

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

We have a few hundreds of images (icons) that we're adding to a map to be shown once our feautures are rendered.

We use (simplified):

```
map.loadImage('url', () => map.addImage('name', image as ImageBitmap));
```

This results in as many http requests as there are images and in our case that is a few hundreds of http requests.

Is there any other way to import images to reduce the number of http calls?

Comment: you should prob create your own sprite file - not sure how to do that but that is how the default mapbox style works and it's only two http calls - all the images are stored in a sprite sheet

Comment: @Malcolm yeah, I've looked into documentation for that but I just can't find my way through it how to actually implement it.